# Angular 8 : No provider for HttpClient in service

Tags: angular8

In order to migrate an Angular 5 project to Angular 8, I've created an empty project with Angular CLI and copied my modules, components and services in my new project structure.
The project builds, but at the execution I've got the classic message "No provider for HttpClient in service" :

```
    ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TimeService -> HttpClient]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TimeService -> HttpClient]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:50573:27)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:52359:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:52285:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:52148:20)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:52359:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:52285:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:52148:20)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:76198:29)
    at _createClass (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:76275:32)
    at _createProviderInstance (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:76231:26)
```

I thing my app.module.ts is ok : I'm importing HttpClientModule and I've put it in @NgModule imports, just after BrowserModule.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent,DelegationsComponent],
    imports:      [BrowserModule,
                  HttpClientModule,
                  GlobalModule.forRoot(),
                  AuthenticationModule,
                   DelegationModule,
                   routing,
                   FormsModule,
                   ReactiveFormsModule,
                   BrowserAnimationsModule,
                   ButtonModule, TableModule, DialogModule, DropdownModule, ToastModule, TabViewModule, InputTextModule, AutoCompleteModule, TooltipModule, CheckboxModule, OverlayPanelModule, MultiSelectModule, CalendarModule ],
    providers:    [APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS, {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: getBaseHref()}],
    bootstrap:    [AppComponent]
})
```

The error seems to be in TimeService. In this service, HttpClient is imported and injected in the contructor.

```
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export class TimeService extends BaseService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient)
```

Then, TimeService is injected in DelegationsComponent.

```
import {TimeService} from "utils/time.service";
@Component({
    moduleId: __moduleName,
    selector: 'delegations',
    templateUrl: './delegations.component.html'
})
export class DelegationsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor(private timeService: TimeService)
```

And you can see DelegationsComponent in my app.module.ts declarations.

Any idea ?
Thank you

**EDIT :** 
By trying to reproduce the problem on a small example, I've found the cause : time.service.ts is not in my angular app but in a folder outside, because I'm sharing it with two other angular apps. I'm including it thanks to the package.json of my apps :

```
"utils": "file:../../../../../utils"
```

So time.service.ts ends in node_modules/utils. If I put it in the src/app directory, it works. Any idea why it doesn't work this way, and how I can share a service amongst several angular apps ?

Comment: check import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: I already have it in app.module.ts. Is it required elsewhere ?

Answer (score 15):

The error =>

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TimeService -> HttpClient]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TimeService -> HttpClient]:
```

Below solution is worked for me and I am using Angular version-9

=> **Need to add** => `import {HttpClientModule}` from `'@angular/common/http';` in `app.module.ts` and also in the [import] array.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide your service in the root (or the components you desire) in order to inject it in the application. Otherwise, the imported `HttpClientModule` will not be imported for the injectable.

For providing in the root, use `providedIn` property like following:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TimeService extends BaseService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
}
```

---

If you want to provide a service in a component, then you need to set it in `providers` property of component decorator like following:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: __moduleName,
    selector: 'delegations',
    templateUrl: './delegations.component.html',
    providers: [
        TimeService
    ]
})
export class DelegationsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor(private timeService: TimeService){}
}
```

Then import `TimeService` and `HttpClientModule` in `app.module.ts` (or in your feature module).

You can find a working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bzvgwn

Comment: In my case it would be providedIn: DelegationsComponent, but as TimeService is injected in DelegationsComponent, it would create a circular dependency. It's not a problem ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It makes TimeService available in AppComponent (if I remove the provider in your sample, I've got NullInjectorError: No provider for TimeService!). But my problem is to have HttpClient in TimeService (StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TimeService -> HttpClient]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!). 
If I add the HttpClientModule import in app.module and the HttpClient injection in time.service in your sample, I don't reproduce my problem.

Comment: Allright I get it. I updated the answer as well as the stackblitz project. You can check it out again. You need to provide the `TimeService` and the `HttpClientModule` in your module (app or feature module)

Comment: Thank you again, but still doesn't work for me. And I can't reproduce my problem on the sample project on stackblitz. Some precisions : my TimeService extends a base service, but I don't think it's the problem. I've tried with this BaseService in stackblitz and it works.

Comment: Ok,I've figured it out. Of course, the problem comes from something I didn't mention, and I'm sorry. TimeService is in a directory outside my angular app, because it's shared amongst three apps. I'm including it with my app package json like this : "utils": "file:../../../../../utils". So TimeService ends in node_modules. Any idea why it doesn't work like this and how I can include a shared service ? Thank you

Comment: It is really hard to tell what is the exact issue without seeing all the relevant code. Maybe I can help if you can reproduce a minimal example in stackblitz or somewhere else.

Comment: Here is a minimal project : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oIlTWNLd_KH4Z0koGuLCWt7lOE5-SRxO
Main : the angular app.
Utils : base service and time service.
You just have to do a yarn install in both and ng serve in the main directory.

Answer (score -5):

import this inside your app.module.ts.This will work

```
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";
```

Comment: The whole @angular/http package doesn't exist anymore. HttpClientModule has replaced HttpModule : https://angular.io/guide/deprecations

Comment: Have you looked at the official docs: https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularhttp